# Eclipse IDE luna is not loading

Tags: eclipse

I have installed Eclipse IDE luna on Ubuntu 14.04 successfully. But when i open the ide  application by clicking the desktop icon ,the ide never loads and an empty window is displayed for a long time and which eventually disappear after some time.

Plese help me in fixing the issue? since there is no error message displayed it is very difficult to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How you installed the eclipse luna in ubuntu 14.04...??

I generally prefer this method to install eclipse luna(latest version).

See in this [Link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/06/install-latest-eclipse-ubuntu-14-04/).

It's always work for me. Try this.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi i have followed same steps,in fact i have followed the same link which you have mentioned here. But i am not sure why it is not loading. I could see eclipse loading for a long time.